# CSS ID doesn't effect sibling elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to affect a sibling element when another element is hovered.
I find this works when I use classes instead, but doesn't when I used IDs. Can someone explain why it works with classes and not IDs

```css
header #Main .Second {
  display: none;
}

.First:hover+.Second {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="Main">
    <div class="First">
      <img src="Image-Here">
    </div>

    <div class="Second">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

When I change the `id="Main"` to `class="Main"` the effect I want happens

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: If you were to change the second selector to `#Main .First:Hover + .Second` it would work.

Comment: @HereticMonkey isn't that basically the same as `.First:hover + .Second` just more specific? Anywho, when I was experimenting with different ways of doing it it wasn't working when I used ID instead of classes

Comment: "just more specific" well, as @Pete points out, that's the whole problem. IDs are more specific than classes, so your second selector (using classes) doesn't override the first (using IDs).